# I need to find the last Space in a XLS Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet with text values, e.g. in A1: "This is the text". I need to find the position of the last space character. Is there an excel formula that will give me the result I want? I have tried FIND and SEARCH, however these start from left, what I need is to start from right.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of about the same vintage: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18617349

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If by blank value you mean "space", and by XLS you mean Excel, then you can use this formula (assuming the test you want to find the last space in is in `A1`):

```
=FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","☃",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))
```

You can divide it into 3 parts:

- `LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))` gives you the number of spaces, let's call it `x`,
- `SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","☃",[x])` will replace the `x`th space (so the last one) by a snowman,
- `FIND("☃",[...])` will give you the position of the snowman. Which is the position of the last space.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks. It took me a while to figure out why it worked inspite of your explanation :)

Comment: +1 for a nice, detailed answer, and the most creative replacement character yet.

Comment: Also works in both LibreOffice Calc and Google Sheets.

Comment: Ingenious, +1. But I find it a bit disappointing that even after 7 years Microsoft couldn't be bothered to create simple "r"-versions of their functions (e.g. rfind to search from the right).

Answer (score 11):

Here's another way, any characters are allowed in A1 (even snowmen!)

`=LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(" ",A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))))`

`FIND` has a third argument that defines the start position of the search, if you apply an array of integer values 1 to n (where n is the length of A1) to that parameter you get an array back with the last number being the position of the last space.

`LOOKUP` then extracts that number by searching for a  value greater than any value that might be found in that array, in which case the **last** number is found

In `Excel 2010` or later you could also use `AGGREGATE` function like this

`=AGGREGATE(14,6,FIND(" ",A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))),1)`

`FIND` returns the same array as before and by using 14 as 1st argument of `AGGREGATE` and 1 as the last you get the largest value in the array, whilst ignoring errors [6]

Comment: works great. Although I was developer some [long] time ago I still can't figure out how and why INDIRECT works :)

Comment: Assuming A1 has 12 characters then this part `"1:"&LEN(A1)` evaluates to "1:12" - that's a string which ROW can't process but INDIRECT converts a string to a valid reference which ROW **can** handle so ROW(1:12) then gives you {1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12}

Comment: Thanks for clarif. Does make some sense now. Which means Find itself implictly works with the array and gets executed for every value as starting position ...

Comment: That's right, FIND returns an array, e.g if A1 contains `barry larry houdini` then FIND will return this array `{6;6;6;6;6;6;12;12;12;12;12;12;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!}` and LOOKUP and/or AGGREGATE will take the last/largest numeric value from that, i.e 12

Comment: Note: this works in LibreOffice Calc. It does not work in Google Sheets, instead finding the first occurrence.