# How do you delimit a column by the last two delimiters only?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list of municipalities and population data I need to put into three columns, and the best way I can figure to do it is delimit the data by the last two delimiters only.

For example, many of the municipalities have names longer than one word, so I can't simply use the space as a global delimiter.

```
 Regional | Municipality | of | Wood | Buffalo | 125,032 | 1-Apr-15
```

But if I could figure out how to do it by the *last two spaces only*, then I could get the municipalities in one column, and the populations in a another.

```
Regional Municipality of Wood Buffalo | 125,032 | 1-Apr-15
```

I've been trying a combination of LEFT, MID, RIGHT, SEARCH, and LEN text functions to try and get what I want, looking at examples from [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-functions-49ec57f9-3d5a-44b2-82da-50dded6e4a68#bkmk_7) for help, but I can't get anything to work the way I want to.

I'm hoping there's some kind of function that can accomplish the task. Something as simple as:

```
=RIGHT(A1,DELIMIT(" ",2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is in A1,

In B1:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","☃",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-1))-1)
```

In C1:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","☃",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-1)),FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","☃",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","☃",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-1)))
```

In D1:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","☃",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))))
```

(and credit where credit is due: Based on 34573r's [formula](https://superuser.com/questions/680769/i-need-to-find-the-last-space-in-a-xls-cell) (complete with snowman)